# FastAPI not running all the functions to return the right values from database

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, twitter, fastapi, twitterapi-python

I am trying to make a twitter points program. Basically, you get points based off of the number of likes, retweets and replies your post with a specified hashtag gets. I made an API to get these points from a database but fastAPI is not doing all the funtions specified to return the correct values.

API code:

```
DATABASE_URL = "mysql+mysqlconnector://root:password@localhost:3306/twitterdb"

database = Database(DATABASE_URL)
metadata_obj = MetaData()
engine = create_engine(
    DATABASE_URL, connect_args={"check_same_thread": False}
)
SessionLocal = sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine)
metadata = sqlalchemy.MetaData()
Base = declarative_base()

user_points = sqlalchemy.Table(
    "points",
    metadata_obj,
    sqlalchemy.Column("username", sqlalchemy.String,),
    sqlalchemy.Column("rt_points", sqlalchemy.Integer,),
    sqlalchemy.Column("reply_points", sqlalchemy.Integer),
    sqlalchemy.Column("like_points", sqlalchemy.Integer),
    sqlalchemy.Column("total_points", sqlalchemy.Integer)
)

engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(
    DATABASE_URL
)
metadata.create_all(engine)

app = FastAPI()
@app.on_event("startup")
async def connect():
    await database.connect()

@app.on_event("shutdown")
async def shutdown():
    await database.disconnect()
    
class UserName(BaseModel):
    rt_points: int
    reply_points: int
    like_points: int 
    total_points : int
    
@app.get('/userdata/', response_model=UserName)
async def get_points(user: str):
    username=user
    metrics.clear()
    tweets_list = tweet_id(username)
    tweets_list.get_tweet_ids(str(username))
    metrics.main()
    summing=summer(username)
    summing.sum_fun(str(username))
    query = user_points.select().where(user_points.c.username == username)
    user = await database.fetch_one(query)
    return {**user}

if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run("main:app", reload= True, host="127.0.0.1", port=5000, log_level="info")
```

code for metrics.py:

```
ids=[]
class tweet_id:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    def get_tweet_ids(self, name):
        try:
            connection = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',
                                                database='twitterdb',
                                                user='root',
                                                password='password')

            cursor = connection.cursor()
            query="truncate table twitterdb.points"
            query1="truncate table twitterdb.Metrics"
            sql_select_query = """SELECT tweetid FROM twitterdb.StreamData WHERE username = %s"""
            # set variable in query
            cursor.execute(query)
            cursor.execute(query1)
            cursor.execute(sql_select_query, (name,))

            # fetch result
            record = cursor.fetchall()

            for row in record:
                ids.append(int(row[0]))

        except mysql.connector.Error as error:
            print("Failed to get record from MySQL table: {}".format(error))

        finally:
            if connection.is_connected():
                cursor.close()
                connection.close()

def create_url():
    tweet_fields = "tweet.fields=public_metrics"
    converted_list = [str(element) for element in ids]
    id_list = ",".join(converted_list)
    url = "https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets?ids={}&{}".format(id_list, tweet_fields)
    return url

#curl 'https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets?ids=1459764778088337413&tweet.fields=public_metrics&expansions=attachments.media_keys&media.fields=public_metrics' --header 'Authorization: Bearer $Bearer

def bearer_oauth(r):
    """
    Method required by bearer token authentication.
    """

    r.headers["Authorization"] = f"Bearer {bearer_token}"
    return r


def connect_to_endpoint(url):
    response = requests.request("GET", url, auth=bearer_oauth)
    print(response.status_code)
    if response.status_code != 200:
        raise Exception(
            "Request returned an error: {} {} {}".format(
                response.status_code, response.text, ids
            )
        )
        return url
    return response.json()


def main():
    def append_to_database(json_response):
    #Loop through each tweet
        for tweet in json_response['data']:  
            # Tweet ID
            tweetid = tweet['id']
            # Tweet metrics
            retweet_count = tweet['public_metrics']['retweet_count']
            reply_count = tweet['public_metrics']['reply_count']
            like_count = tweet['public_metrics']['like_count']
            quote_count = tweet['public_metrics']['quote_count']
            connect(tweetid, retweet_count, reply_count, like_count, quote_count)
    def connect(tweetid, retweet_count, reply_count, like_count, quote_count):
        """
        connect to MySQL database and insert twitter data
        """
        try:
            con = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',
            database='twitterdb', user='root', password='passsword', charset='utf8')

            if con.is_connected():
                """
                Insert twitter data
                """
                cursor = con.cursor(buffered=True)
                # twitter, golf
                delete_previous_data_query = "truncate table Metrics"
                query = "INSERT INTO Metrics (tweetid,retweet_count,reply_count,like_count,quote_count) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"
                cursor.execute(delete_previous_data_query)
                cursor.execute(query, (tweetid,retweet_count,reply_count,like_count,quote_count))
                con.commit()
                

        except Error as e:
            print(e)

        cursor.close()
        con.close()

        return
    url = create_url()
    json_response = connect_to_endpoint(url)
    append_to_database(json_response)

#Function to calculate sum of points and display it
class summer:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    def sum_fun(self, name):

        try:
            con = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',
            database='twitterdb', user='root', password='password', charset='utf8')

            if con.is_connected():
                cursor = con.cursor(buffered=True)
                def create_points_table():
                    query= ("INSERT INTO twitterdb.points(username, rt_points,reply_points,like_points,total_points) (SELECT %s, SUM(quote_count + retweet_count) * 150, SUM(reply_count) * 50, SUM(like_count) * 10, SUM(quote_count + retweet_count) * 150 + SUM(reply_count) * 50 + SUM(like_count) * 10 FROM twitterdb.Metrics)")

                    cursor.execute(query, (name,))
                    con.commit()
                create_points_table();

        except Error as e:
            print(e)
        cursor.close()
        con.close()
        
def clear():
    """
    connect to MySQL database and insert twitter data
    """
    try:
        con = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',
        database='twitterdb', user='root', password='password', charset='utf8')

        if con.is_connected():
            cursor = con.cursor(buffered=True)
            clear_points = ("truncate table twitterdb.points")
            cursor.execute(clear_points)
    except Error as e:
        print(e)
    cursor.close()
    con.close()

    return
```

What happens here is that there's a database named `twitterdb` with the tables `StreamData`, `metrics`, and `points`.
StreamData containts tweetids and usernames of the posts that were tweeted with the specified hashtag and it is build with the Streaming API.

Here the issues is that, suppose I have the following usernames `mark` and `ramon` in the streamdata table. So when I input the username via the API as `mark` no issues happen, it returns the correct points for `mark`, but if I then enter something like `mark1` or any random value, it returns the points for `mark` again. But then if I enter `ramon` it gives the right points for `ramon` but then if I enter the random values again, I get the same points for `ramon`.

Furthermore, the first time when we start the API and if we enter a random value, it returns an error that is specified in the exception as defined in `connect_to_endpoint` function.

The code logic here is that,
We enter a username via the API, and the `get_tweet_ids` function looks for that username in the `streamdata` table and selects all the tweet ids corresponding to that username and saves it to a list, `ids`. This list of ids is given to the twitter metrics API endpoint and the required values from the response is saved to the table `metrics`.
Then, the `sum_fun` is called to select the sum of values of likes, rts and replies from the `metrics` table, multiply it with the specified points and save it to the table `points` along with the username.
The API at last  returns the values in the table `points` matching the username.

How can I get it to stop returning the values for random data? If an invalid data is given, it must raise the exception in `connect_to_endpoint` function, but it just returns whatever value is in the table `points` previously.
I tried multiple approaches to this like, clearing the values of `points` before all other functions and checking to return only the values corresponding to the username in the points table. But neither of them worked. When the username was checked in the points table after running it with random values, it contained the random value but with the points of the previous valid username.

NOTE: The table `points` is a temporary table and values are assigned only when an API call is made.

I am a complete beginner to all this and this is more of a pet project I have been working on, so please help out. Any and all help and guidance regarding my logic and design and a fix for this will be of much use. Thanks.

Comment: Quick question, have you tried using the twitter api for random gibberish just in curl? So you can be certain that the api isn't the culprit.

Comment: you shoud make some tests with multiple random non present names and see if you always get the last found data, it would suggest that you have a variable that is alocated only if you found a match and always return it's content.

Comment: @PavelHamerník Yes I did try that. It returns an error if I give random number for tweet ids.

Comment: @BastienB Yes, I did make those tests and they do always return the last found data. Also, if I restart the API and give a random name as input it returns the expected error message. This random value thing only happens if and only when a right value is given previously.

Answer (score 0):

if the code that you have provided for metrics.py is correct your problem should comme from how you declare the variable ids.

in your code you have declare it as a global so it will not be reset at every function call or class instance creation.

what you should to is declare it in get_tweet_ids()

```py
class tweet_id:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    def get_tweet_ids(self, name):
        ids=[]  # modification here
        try:
            connection = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',
                                                database='twitterdb',
                                                user='root',
                                                password='password')

            cursor = connection.cursor()
            query="truncate table twitterdb.points"
            query1="truncate table twitterdb.Metrics"
            sql_select_query = """SELECT tweetid FROM twitterdb.StreamData WHERE username = %s"""
            # set variable in query
            cursor.execute(query)
            cursor.execute(query1)
            cursor.execute(sql_select_query, (name,))

            # fetch result
            record = cursor.fetchall()

            for row in record:
                ids.append(int(row[0]))
            return ids  # modification here
   
        except mysql.connector.Error as error:
            print("Failed to get record from MySQL table: {}".format(error))

        finally:
            if connection.is_connected():
                cursor.close()
                connection.close()
```

with this you will have a new instance of ids at every get_tweet_ids call.
You will have to change the rest of your code according to this return statement

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer. This seems to be the right solution, but using the ids as a local variable for just the class tweet_id would prevent the running of the function `create_url` since it requires making use of the variable `ids`. Is there a way to access the variable outside the class and make use of it for those functions?

Comment: Can't you add it as function parameter? In the example I gave get_tweet_ids() return ids value so you can reuse it where you previously used the global

Comment: Sorry, but I am not exactly sure what you meant by adding it as a function parameter. I did use the `return ids` line in the code, but I still get an error saying
`line 52, in create_url
    converted_list = [str(element) for element in ids]
NameError: name 'ids' is not defined
`

Comment: 'You will have to change the rest of your code according to this return statement', create_url need ids so you just have to convert the function to create_url(ids) so you can pass ids as argument

Comment: Sorry if this sounds dumb, I am still learning this stuff. But just replacing `create_url` with `create_url(ids)` won't do anything right? Since the `ids` are still inside the class we won't be able to access it? Could you please clarify further on the modifications that I need to do?